# Problema con imagecopy() arroja error

Tags: php, imagen

Tengo esta función pero al ejecutarlo me arroja este error :

> imagedestroy(): supplied argument is not a valid Image resource
>
> imagecopy(): supplied argument is not a valid Image resource
>
> imagejpeg(): supplied argument is not a valid Image resource

```
<?php 
$posiX=400;
$posiY=150;

$logo="http://dominio.com/images/ejemplo.png";
 $fondo"http://dominio.com/images/ejemplo.jpg"; 
foto($fondo, $logo, $posiX, $posiY);

function foto($img_original, $marcadeagua, $posiX, $posiY){


list($old_x, $old_y, $type) = getimagesize($img_original);
    switch ($type)
    {
        case 'jpg':   //   gif -> jpg
            $src_img = imagecreatefromjpg($img_original);
            break;

        case 'jpeg':   //   jpeg -> jpg
            $src_img = imagecreatefromjpeg($img_original); 
            break;

        case 'png':  //   png -> jpg
            $src_img = imagecreatefrompng($img_original);
            break;
    }

//tomar el origen (logo)
$marcadeagua= imagecreatefrompng($marcadeagua);

//las posiciones en donde ubicar - se reciben por POST
$xmarcaagua = $posiX;
$ymarcaagua = $posiY;

//se obtiene el ancho y el largo del logo
$ximagen = imagesx($marcadeagua);
$yimagen = imagesy($marcadeagua);

//COPIAR (observar las variables que se usan)
imagecopy($src_img, $marcadeagua, $xmarcaagua, $ymarcaagua,0, 0,
          $ximagen, $yimagen); // linea donde se genera el error imagecopy()


//Generar el archivo
imagejpeg($src_img, '../images/originalrand.jpg');


//faltaba destruirla (hay que ser prolijos)
imagedestroy( $src_img );
 }


 ?>
```

¿Qué pasa? no entiendo qué hago mal .

Comment: Puedes indicar el error que te arroja?

Comment: en la parte superior puse los errores que da : 
    imagecopy(): supplied argument is not a valid Image resource

Comment: comprueba la ruta, me suena que la ruta debe ser local y no la url del la imagen

Comment: `$fondo"http://dominio.com/images/ejemplo.jpg";` debería ser `$fondo="http://dominio.com/images/ejemplo.jpg";`

Comment: me sigue dando error asi ponga las rutas locales ,  tipo : ../images/ejemplo.jpg"  .. que otra cosa podría ser?

Comment: Por casualidad que version de PHP esta utilizando?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema viene por el uso de `list()` en `PHP7` su comportamiento ha sido cambiado y ya tampoco se puede utilizar con indices de tipo string.

[Vease las notas de list()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.list.php)

Debido a que que `list()` se ha invertido no te esta asignando los valores que esperas en las variables por lo que no se cumple ninguna condicion del case y nunca se ejecuta `imagecreatefrom_*()`.

Primero veamos que nos devuelve `getimagesize($img_original)` con una imagen png de 200px de ancho y 100px de alto:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 200 // Ancho
    [1] => 100 // Alto
    [2] => 3
    [3] => width="200" height="100"
    [bits] => 8
    [mime] => image/png
)
```

Los datos que nos interesan del array son el mime `[mime] => image/png`, el ancho `[0] => 200` y el alto `[1] => 100`. Sabiendo esto corrijamos algunas cosas de la función:

```
function foto($img_original, $marcadeagua, $posiX, $posiY) {
    // list($old_x, $old_y, $type) = getimagesize($img_original);

    //optenemos array con la info
    $info = getimagesize($img_original);
    // pasamos el mime al switch y corregimos los case, ñadmos un default
    switch ($info['mime'])
    {
        case 'image/jpg':
            $src_img = imagecreatefromjpg($img_original);
            break;
        case 'image/jpeg':
            $src_img = imagecreatefromjpeg($img_original); 
            break;
        case 'image/png':
            $src_img = imagecreatefrompng($img_original);
            break;
        default:
            return false;
    }

    //tomar el origen (logo)
    $marcadeagua= imagecreatefrompng($marcadeagua);

    //las posiciones en donde ubicar - se reciben por POST
    $xmarcaagua = $posiX;
    $ymarcaagua = $posiY;

    //se obtiene el ancho y el largo del logo
    $ximagen = imagesx($marcadeagua);
    $yimagen = imagesy($marcadeagua);

    //COPIAR (observar las variables que se usan)
    imagecopy($src_img, $marcadeagua, $xmarcaagua, $ymarcaagua,0, 0,
              $ximagen, $yimagen); // linea donde se genera el error imagecopy()

    //Generar el archivo
    imagejpeg($src_img, 'originalrand.jpg');

    //faltaba destruirla (hay que ser prolijos)
    imagedestroy( $src_img );
}



foto($fondo, $logo, $posiX, $posiY);
```

Hemos eliminado el `list()`, en su lugar tenemos un array `$info`. En el `switch` pasamos el mime obtenido `$info['mime']` y ajustamos los `case` para que coincidan con los mimes.

Comment: Excelente!, me ha funcionado, mil gracias !